# orderBy case insensitive in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do I use the filter orderBy to sort data in regardless of the case (case insensitive) in an ng-repeat clause? Do I need to write a custom function to do that? If so are there any examples please? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no "ignore the case" parameter. You'll have to build your own sorting method. In the example below, I needed to sort a list of users by "display_name", case insensitive. I transformed all the displayed name into a lowercase string in the controller.

Here's what I have in my controller:

```
$scope.sortingFn = function( user ) {
    return user.display_name.toLowerCase();
}
```

And in the view:

```
ng-repeat="user in users | orderby:sortingFn"
```

Comment: It looks like angular does case-insensitive sorting now, but your answer helped me with a similar problem.

Comment: That's a good news! No more hack needed :) haven't tried it yet though.

Answer (score 4):

It is case-insensitive. See the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy#the-default-comparator) regarding its default comparator:

> The default, built-in comparator should be sufficient for most
>   usecases. In short, it compares numbers numerically, strings
>   alphabetically (and **case-insensitively**), for objects falls back to
>   using their index in the original collection, and sorts values of
>   different types by type.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply order by any key you want, if they are primitives, order by a nested object will be more complicated

Here the angularjs [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

```
ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:'-age'"
```

Comment: i'm trying to order, say by last name, but case insensitively. so like `ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:'lastName'" in regardless of alphabetical case ordering.